# Extracting consecutive True values from Boolean array, while keeping indices

Tags: python, boolean

I have a problem that has stumped me. I have a Boolean array (n=1320) in which I would like to extract sequences of at least 6 consecutive True values and keep the original indices.

For example:

```
Input:  [True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, True , True , False, False, False]
Output: [True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Thanks in advance (Working in Python 3.8, with Jupyter Lab)

/Johan

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. This looks like you just keep `True` if either 1 or 2 is `True`. Also, in the example above, you do not have 6 or more consecutive `True` values. Can you give an example that demonstrates all of the situations you have described please?

Comment: Yes, I did think of that, but the issue is first dropping sequences of ```True´´´ that  is less than six in a row.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that because you haven't provided an example. Please do so, and I'll probably be able to help.

Comment: Okay, so I have a boolean array [True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, False], and I only want to keep the the sequences of six or more True values in a row. I.e. output for this would ideally be [True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]. Hope this is clearer, thank you

Comment: I'm closer to understanding, but when does Array2 come into it? You can edit your original post with the Edit button, and you can add code blocks by using three grave \`\`\` symbols both before and after the code. You can also make `inline code` by using just one grave symbol \`like this\`.

Comment: Edited, and dropped the second array, since your first comment solved that!

Comment: Fantastic edit! My final question is, what should happen if there are more than 6 `True` values in a row?

Comment: If there are more, then I would like to keep them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does the trick:

```py
arr1 = [True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, True , True , False, False, False]

def check_for_six(arr):
    arr = arr.copy()                   # avoid mutating the original list
    counting = []                      # keep track of True indexes, to count them later
    for i in range(len(arr)):          # cycle by index
        is_last = i + 1 >= len(arr)    # True if this is the last index in the array
        if arr[i] == True:
            counting.append(i)         # add value to list if True
        if is_last or arr[i] == False: # when we are at the last entry, or find a False
            if len(counting) < 6:      # check the length of our True indexes, and if less than 6
                for j in counting:
                    arr[j] = False     # make each False
            counting = []
    return arr

print( check_for_six(arr1) )
```

Output:

```
[True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you for the help and assistance, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are several problem with your test case. First your test case doesn't have 6 consecutive `True`s. However an output is returned.
Here is the code you might find useful. Note that I changed the 2 arrays so that they contain 6 consecutive `True`s. You might want to delete the last 6 items in Array1 and Array2 to see whether it works or not.
if I'm mistaken in getting the point of your question please tell it. Your question is a bit unclear.
Goodluck.

```
Array1 = [True, True, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, True]
Array2 = [True, True, False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True]

isConsecutive = False

for i in range(len(Array1)):
    try:
        if Array1[i] and Array1[i+1] and Array1[i+2] and Array1[i+3] and Array1[i+4] and Array1[i+5]:
            isConsecutive = True
            break
    except:
        pass
    
    try:
        if Array2[i] and Array2[i+1] and Array2[i+2] and Array2[i+3] and Array2[i+4] and Array2[i+5]:
            isConsecutive = True
            break
    except:
        pass

Output = []
if isConsecutive:
    for i in range(len(Array1)):
        if Array1[i] or Array2[i]:
            Output.append(True)
        else:
            Output.append(False)
    print(Output)
else:
    print("Your arrays don't have six or more consecutive 'True's!")
```

Output:

```
[True, True, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```